# Limit involving floor function: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \left\lfloor\frac1x \right\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm studying calculus right now but I'm stuck at solving a limit involving floor function.

The problem is to find $$\lim_{x\to 0}x \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

My first thought was to let $x=1/t$ so when ${x\to 0+}$ then ${t\to \infty}$ so it seems $\lim_{t\to \infty}[t]/t$ doesn't exist. But I can't go any further and don't know whether my thought is correct. It seems $t=N+\delta$ doesn't help because t goes to infinity. Can it be proved by the epsilon-delta method or something else?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: A hint on $\LaTeX$: there are symbols `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` which render as $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ to represent the floor function.

Comment: @CiaPan  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: See also: [Does $\lim_{x \to 0+} \left(x\lfloor \frac{a}{x} \rfloor\right)=a?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876062), [Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} (x\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879530) or [How can I calculate this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/345868)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345868/how-can-i-calculate-this-limit-lim-limits-x-to-0-x-left-lfloor-frac1x-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\frac  {t-1} t \leq \frac {[t]} t \leq \frac t t$ so $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac {[t]} t =1$.  So $\lim_{x \to 0+} x[\frac 1 x]=1$. But $\lim_{t \to -\infty} \frac {[t]} t$ is also $1$ so $\lim_{x \to 0} x[\frac 1 x]=1$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect the right limits exists.

Answer (score 4):

We have that for any $\frac1x\in[n,n+1) \implies \left[\frac1x\right]=n$ and $x \in \left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$ then

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\le x \cdot \left[\frac1x\right]\le \frac{n}{n}=1$$

then since $x\to 0^+ \implies n\to \infty$, by squeeze theorem the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $x\ne0$,
$$
\frac1x-1\lt\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor\le\frac1x
$$
For $x\gt0$,
$$
\overbrace{1-x}^{1-|x|}\lt x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor\le1
$$
For $x\lt0$,
$$
1\le x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor\lt\overbrace{1-x}^{1+|x|}
$$
Therefore, for all $x\ne0$,
$$
1-|x|\lt x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor\lt1+|x|
$$
Now apply the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}\frac{\lfloor z\rfloor}{z}=1$$ seems obvious.

---

For the skepticals,

$$\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}\frac{\lfloor z\rfloor}{z}=\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}\frac{z}{z}-\lim_{z\to\pm\infty}\frac{\{z\}}{z}=1-0.$$